# x509 certificate parsing libraries for Java

Tags: java, certificate, x509

Any recommended crypto libraries for Java. What I need is the ability to parse X.509 Certificates to extract the information contained in them.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Java, java.security.cert.CertificateFactory.

"A certificate factory for X.509 must return certificates that are an instance of java.security.cert.X509Certificate"

Answer (score 10):

There's a lot more in most certificates than what's handled by `java.security.cert.X509Certificate`. If you need to parse extension values, check out the [Bouncy Castle Crypto API](http://www.bouncycastle.org/index.html). (C# version is offered too.)

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't need crypto libraries, it ships with that functionality already.  In particular, java.security.cert.X509Certificate.

Answer (score 0):

You might also have a look at [Keyczar](http://www.keyczar.org/), developed by google. This library tries to make security as simple as possible and might be easier to use than the standard java libraries...

Comment: I don't see x509 support in that API.