# Parse a data, security cert X509v3 extensions

Tags: python, security, parsing, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

I have basically written a custom python script to parse a security certificate data and load the values into a table. But I would like to know if there is any library in python which does the same work for me. My thoughts are it would be better to use a lib to parse the data than to custom script to do it (Or) Is there any other better way to load this data into table / Parse the data

Logic of my script : Since the data looks more like a YAML like string, I have formatted the data into a YAML like string. Then it was easy for me to convert into CSV and load into a table.

Format of the cert data is given below (example taken from wiki)

```
Certificate:
Data:
    Version: 3 (0x2)
    Serial Number:
        XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
    Issuer: C=BE, O=XX nv-sa, CN=XXX - SHA256 - G2
    Validity
        Not Before: Nov 21 08:00:00 2016 GMT
        Not After : Nov 22 07:59:59 2017 GMT
    Subject: C=US, ST=California, L=San Francisco, O=XX XX, Inc., CN=*.XX.org
    Subject Public Key Info:
        Public Key Algorithm: ZZ
            Public-Key: (256 bit)
            pub: 
            ASN1 OID: prime256v1
            NIST CURVE: P-256
    X509v3 extensions:
        X509v3 Key Usage: critical
            Digital Signature, Key Agreement
        Authority Information Access: 
            CA Issuers - URI:http://../..
            OCSP - URI:http://../..
        X509v3 Certificate Policies: 
            Policy: X.X.X.X.X
              CPS: https://XXX
            Policy: XX.XX.XX.XX.XX
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it looks like a YAML file, but badly indented. You need to re-indent it.

You can [pyyaml](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation) library to parse it. Here is a sample:

```
import yaml

content = """\
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number: 10:e6:fc:62:b7:41:8a:d5:00:5e:45:b6
Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
Issuer: C=BE, O=GlobalSign nv-sa, CN=GlobalSign Organization Validation CA - SHA256 - G2
Validity:
    Not Before: Nov 21 08:00:00 2016 GMT
    Not After : Nov 22 07:59:59 2017 GMT
"""

obj = yaml.load(content)
```

You get:

```
{'Certificate': {'Data': {'Serial Number': '10:e6:fc:62:b7:41:8a:d5:00:5e:45:b6',
                          'Version': '3 (0x2)'}},
 'Issuer': 'C=BE, O=GlobalSign nv-sa, CN=GlobalSign Organization Validation CA '
           '- SHA256 - G2',
 'Signature Algorithm': 'sha256WithRSAEncryption',
 'Validity': {'Not After': 'Nov 22 07:59:59 2017 GMT',
              'Not Before': 'Nov 21 08:00:00 2016 GMT'}}
```

You can use an [online YAML parser](http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com) to check your data.

Comment: Yes, that is kind of my current solution. But I am looking for some libraries to do that work for me . Since the data might have variable columns (some columns might or might not be there for some certs. So I am looking for more flexible way to do this ) For example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143632/crypto-x509-certificate-parsing-libraries-for-python tells something about this but the docs are not clear enough