# Extraction of sha1 from X.509 openssl certificate in Java

Tags: java, x509certificate, x509

I must write a Java implementation of an X.509 openssl certificate parser, but I have a problem: I do not know how to get the sha1 for the validation of certificates.
Can anyone help me to understand what I should do? I know that there is a method `getTBSCertificate()` in Java, but I have to rewrite it for my purpose.

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143523/x509-certificate-parsing-libraries-for-java

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you mean the sha1 which is commonly shown as the 'fingerprint' in the browsers and OS tools -- you need 1) the raw cert as DER; and then 2) sha1 it and 3) translate that to the usual double-digit-hex/colon separated string.

As to 1; getEncoded() from   java.security.cert.Certificate gets you that.

As to 2: MessageDigest has that function.

As to 3: I'll leave that to you :)

```
... someFoo(X509Certificate cert) {
    MessageDigest sha1 = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1");
    System.out.println("  Subject " + cert.getSubjectDN());
    System.out.println("   Issuer  " + cert.getIssuerDN());
    sha1.update(cert.getEncoded());
    System.out.println("   sha1    " + toHexString(sha1.digest()));
    System.out.println();
  }
```

should do the trick. This output matches that of the java keytool.

Dw.

Comment: That's correct for the fingerprint indeed. My guess is that the question may also be about verifying the signature... Here are a couple of recent related questions: [about fingerprints](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/14330/2435) and [about signatures (and CAs)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10411433/372643).