# Netty SSL : how to write a TrustManager

Tags: java, ssl, netty

I've read plenty of stuff to setup my SSL client/server system (no HTTP).

I inspired myself from [the secure chat example](https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/3/src/main/java/org/jboss/netty/example/securechat) and [the websocket ssl server example](https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/master/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/http/websocketx/sslserver).
Already created my cert.jks file with the command

```
keytool -genkey -alias app-keysize 2048 -validity 36500
-keyalg RSA -dname "CN=app"
-keypass mysecret-storepass mysecret
-keystore cert.jks
```

In the secure chat example there is this class:

```
public class SecureChatTrustManagerFactory extends TrustManagerFactorySpi {

    private static final TrustManager DUMMY_TRUST_MANAGER = new X509TrustManager() {
        @Override
        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return new X509Certificate[0];
        }

        @Override
        public void checkClientTrusted(
                X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
            // Always trust - it is an example.
            // You should do something in the real world.
            // You will reach here only if you enabled client certificate auth,
            // as described in SecureChatSslContextFactory.
            System.err.println(
                    "UNKNOWN CLIENT CERTIFICATE: " + chain[0].getSubjectDN());
        }

        @Override
        public void checkServerTrusted(
                X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
            // Always trust - it is an example.
            // You should do something in the real world.
            System.err.println(
                    "UNKNOWN SERVER CERTIFICATE: " + chain[0].getSubjectDN());
        }
    };

    public static TrustManager[] getTrustManagers() {
        return new TrustManager[] { DUMMY_TRUST_MANAGER };
    }

    @Override
    protected TrustManager[] engineGetTrustManagers() {
        return getTrustManagers();
    }

    @Override
    protected void engineInit(KeyStore keystore) throws KeyStoreException {
        // Unused
    }

    @Override
    protected void engineInit(ManagerFactoryParameters managerFactoryParameters)
            throws InvalidAlgorithmParameterException {
        // Unused
    }
}
```

How do you implement this class properly?

And in this code (in the SecureChatSslContextFactory class):

```
    SSLContext serverContext = null;
    SSLContext clientContext = null;
    try {
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        ks.load(SecureChatKeyStore.asInputStream(),
                SecureChatKeyStore.getKeyStorePassword());

        // Set up key manager factory to use our key store
        KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(algorithm);
        kmf.init(ks, SecureChatKeyStore.getCertificatePassword());

        // Initialize the SSLContext to work with our key managers.
        serverContext = SSLContext.getInstance(PROTOCOL);
        serverContext.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), null, null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Error(
                "Failed to initialize the server-side SSLContext", e);
    }

    try {
        clientContext = SSLContext.getInstance(PROTOCOL);
        clientContext.init(null, SecureChatTrustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Error(
                "Failed to initialize the client-side SSLContext", e);
    }
```

Why do they put `null` instead of `tmf.getTrustManagers()` in the line `serverContext.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), null, null);` ?

Answer (score 9):

> How do you implement this class properly?

You need to define a way to check that you trust the certificate at `chain[0]` one way or another. If you don't, throw a `CertificateException`. (Here the `SecureChatTrustManagerFactory` never throws anything, so it bypasses the verification, which can make the connection open to MITM attacks.)

If you want to do this verification semi-manually, you can use the [Java PKI API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/certpath/CertPathProgGuide.html), although [it can be a bit tedious](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10414727/372643), even on relatively simple use cases.

Generally speaking, the right thing to do is *not* to implement your own. Leave that to the `TrustManagerFactory` (more or less in the same way as it's done with the `KeyManagerFactory`). By the way, in both cases, I'd recommend using `Key/TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm()` for the value of `algorithm`, unless you have a good reason not to. It's at least a better default value than `SunX509` which I've seen hard-coded in many cases (and which in fact isn't the default TMF algorithm value).

You can initialise a TMF from your own truststore (an instance of `KeyStore` that you can load specifically for this connection, for example).

> Why do they put null instead of tmf.getTrustManagers() in the line
>   serverContext.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), null, null); ?

`null` for the trust managers and `null` for the `SecureRandom` fall back to the default values. This will be a default trust manager initialised with the default TMF algorithm (usually `PKIX`), using the default trust store (using the location in `javax.net.ssl.trustStore`, or falling back to the `jssecacerts` file or `cacerts`). More details in the [JSSE reference guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#Customization).

Comment: Still didn't manage to make something working...
I don't see how to implement my own TrustManagerFactory

Comment: Don't implement your own TMF, use the existing one.

Comment: Sorry, I meant I coulnd't implement my own SecureChatSslContextFactory