# Get ASN1 Declarations from DER

Tags: java, c++, ssl, encryption, cryptography

How to get ASN1 Declarations from DER file.

I have a der file like .der or pem file like . I am looking to see how to get the ASN1 declaration file.

EDIT:

I tried using BouncyCastle and 
Libasn1 but all of them require an asn1 declaration to process it.

Comment: What kind of structure is stored the DER file? Your own custom structure or anything well known?

Comment: @Jariq I have no idea but I know this http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-x509-parse.php works well.

Comment: So you just want to parse X.509 certificate?

Comment: In what programming language?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48824/discussion-between-user2789433-and-jariq)

Comment: I edited your question to change _deceleration_ to _declaration_. Please send me a reply if I was wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"DER file" contains only a single specific DER encoded structure. It does not contain ASN.1 declaration of that structure. Generally it is possible to parse unknown DER encoded structure but it is nearly impossible to interpret its individual fields without knowing the exact definition of the structure.

For example: You know that your DER file contains X.509 certificate, but you don't know its ASN.1 definition. In order to correctly process and interpret parsed structure you need to find the document which contains ASN.1 definition and description of X.509 certificate structure - in this case the correct document should be [RFC 528](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5280.txt)0.

But this is usually too low level approach. When you work with higher level languages or cryptographic toolkits it is rather rare to work at ASN.1 level because they provide high level parsers and classes that wrap parsed information. [See this question for example on X.509 certificate parsing in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143523/x509-certificate-parsing-libraries-for-java).